# How to continue the function only after the coroutine completes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, coroutine

```
void Generate()
{
    StartCoroutine(FallDelayCoroutine());
    print("time3- " + Time.time);
}

IEnumerator FallDelayCoroutine()
{     
    print("time1- "+ Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    print("time2- " + Time.time);
}
```

Output:

> time1- 0
>   time3- 0
>   time2- 3.0146

Output that i want is:

> time1- 0
>   time2- 3
>   time3- 3

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html seems to answer your question I think (though I'm not experienced with unity). The second example in particular seems to be exactly what you want...

Comment: The point of a coroutine is that it *doesn't* do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html seems to have an example that is almost identical to what you are trying to do:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // - After 0 seconds, prints "Starting 0.0"
    // - After 2 seconds, prints "WaitAndPrint 2.0"
    // - After 2 seconds, prints "Done 2.0"
    print("Starting " + Time.time);

    // Start function WaitAndPrint as a coroutine. And wait until it is completed.
    // the same as yield WaitAndPrint(2.0);
    yield return StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0F));
    print("Done " + Time.time);
}

// suspend execution for waitTime seconds
IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
}
```

The key point seems to be that their `Start` routine returns IEnumerator and then uses `yield return StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0F));` to force it to wait on that method before continuing.

So the equivalent for you would be:

```
IEnumerator Generate()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(FallDelayCoroutine());
    print("time3- " + Time.time);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559520/7111561) using two Coroutines you could also add a callback like e.g.

```
IEnumerator FallDelayCoroutine(Action whenDone)
{     
    print("time1- "+ Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    print("time2- " + Time.time);

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}
```

and call it either using e.g. a lambda expression

```
void Generate()
{
    StartCoroutine(FallDelayCoroutine(() => {
        print("time3- " + Time.time);
    }));  
}
```

or with a method

```
void Generate()
{
    StartCoroutine(FallDelayCoroutine(OnFallDelayDone));  
}

private void OnFallDelayDone()
{
    print("time3- " + Time.time);
}
```